# Comando DEFRAG /U C: para que se ejecute en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hola necesito que el comando DEFRAG /U C: se ejecute desde C#, cual seria el código para que se ejecute? Lo estoy haciendo desde visual studio
[image: Que al presionar el boton "button2" se ejecute el codigo DEFRAG /U C: en cmd]

Que al presionar el boton "button2" se ejecute el codigo DEFRAG /U C: en cmd

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Por favor dinos qué has investigado y comparte el código que has escrito para poder encontrar una solución apropiada.

Comment: Para comenzar, puedo decirte que utilizarás `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",comandoACorrer);` Lee un poco acerca del Namespace y la clase, y más acerca del Método `Start()`